# Interrogation about the Spring Cloud local-configuration connector and arbitrary properties

Tags: spring-cloud

I have a number of properties (such as google api keys for instance) that I would like to make available through the `spring-cloud.properties` file (see spring cloud local-configuration connector documentation [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/tree/v1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector)).

Here is what I did:

1) Put my google api key in the `spring-cloud.properties` file as follows:

```
spring.cloud.appId:    bignibou
spring.cloud.database: mysql://root:root@localhost:3306/bignibou_dev
google_api.key: AIzaSyBjHuQsAxxx
```

2) Try to load it as follows:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ Profiles.DEFAULT, Profiles.CLOUD, Profiles.DEV, Profiles.CAPACITY_TEST })
public class CloudConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public ApplicationInstanceInfo applicationInfo() {
        return cloud().getApplicationInstanceInfo();
    }

}

...

@Autowired
private ApplicationInstanceInfo applicationInstanceInfo;
```

However it seems that the `properties` variable of my `applicationInstanceInfo` is always empty...

See source code: [empty map](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/v1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-localconfig-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/localconfig/LocalConfigConnector.java#L90)

Is this intended behavior? How is the local configuration connector meant to be used in order to retrieve arbitrary properties such as the google api key (which is going to be different in dev and in the cloud).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In the documentation link you provided it says that "If the connector is activated, it will iterate through all the available properties for keys matching the pattern `spring.cloud.{serviceId}`". So your `google_api.key` is not going to end up in a service info. Maybe you should just put it in a regular Spring property source (e.g. `application.properties` in a Spring Boot app)? It's not clear what you wanted to do with it exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply Dave. I actually wanted to leverage spring cloud connector in order to externalize arbitrary properties such as my google_api key and retrieve this and other properties the same way whether in dev (local) or in the cloud. Am I mistaken in my use of the spring cloud connector?

Comment: Let me also add another relevant point: I meant to have this property value in an environment variable (in the cloud) and in a spring-cloud.properties file (for local dev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to be resolvable from a file locally and override with an environment variable, just use placeholders, e.g.

```
@Value("${GOOGLE_API_KEY:${google_api.key}}
private String googleKey;
```

and put it in a regular external properties file (use `application.properties` with Spring Boot, or just a `@PropertySource(...)` in your `@Configuration`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave. Perfect!  I was not aware of this syntax.